# Python requests vs. urllib2

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, python-requests, partial

I have used requests library for many times and I know it has a ton of advantages. However, I was trying to retrieve the following Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax

and requests.get retrieves it partially:

```
response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax', verify=False)
html = response.text
```

I tried it using urllib2 and urllib2.urlopen and it retrieves the same page completely:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax').read()
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it using requests?

By the way, looking at the number of times this post has been viewed, I realized that people are interested to know the differences between these two libraries. If anyone knows about other differences between these two libraries, I'll appreciate it if they edit this question or post an answer and add those differences.

Comment: `print requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax").text
` worked for me. Did you pass any extra parameter?

Comment: @user, please reduce your problematic program to the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the error, (I should think 4-5 lines would demonstrate the problem), and copy-paste that entire program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Per your request, I added the code in my question. By the way, @fasouto, if you take a look at the result, you will see the end of the document is not retrieved completely.

Comment: They compare equal for me if I remove `headers` from your `requests.get` version. You aren't, by any chance, assuming they're different by comparing their lengths, without looking at their types?

Comment: Let me be clearer: if you compare the lengths with `len()` without noticing that the `urllib2` result is a UTF-8-encoded byte `str` and the `requests.get` result is a `unicode`, then any page that contains a non-ASCII character will show a slightly smaller number for `requests.get`. That's not a "partial response". That's everything working fine.

Comment: If you're certain that this is not what you're seeing, that you have converted them to the same type and still see a difference, then can you take an example page and find and post the difference in content between the two results? It's hard to guess what you're seeing if I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Dan Getz, thank you for clarifying it. I should clarify my question too. When I save requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax").text into a file and, by opening it in a browser, compare it with urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Land_value_tax').read(), the former one ends with section "Edit of 05-17-11" and the body of this section is incomplete. However, the latter one goes to the end of the page, including sections: "Need to Explain What Land Value Is and Its Causes", "Objections", "Bare URL references", "Observed incidence", "Categories", ....

Comment: Ok, then please provide us your value `header` that you use in `requests.get`, because when I don't use it, I get the full, identical page as with `urllib2`. (I haven't been able to test exactly what you use because you left out the value of `header`.) Does removing the `headers` parameter fix it for you?

Comment: Re-reading @Igor's answer and your comment makes me think this has to be what's happening. I'd write an answer, but I can't find any references about how Wikipedia serves pages to different browsers/devices.

Comment: @Dan Getz, Sorry if the header in my question is confusing. As you can see in my previous comment. I also tried it using no more parameters and received the same response. Anyway, I'll remove the header from my question. I am curious why your result is different from mine! Do you think it may be related to the software version. In my case: requests (2.3.0), Python (2.7), OS (WIN 8).

Comment: Doesn't look like it's the software version; I just tested on requests 2.3.0, 2.4.3, 2.5.3, 2.6.2, and 2.7.0 and did not see your issue on any of them. I'm on Python 2.7.9 on Linux. I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @Dan Getz, Thank you for the time you spent to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me the problem lies in the scripting on the target page. The js-driven content is rendered in here (especially i found calls to [mediawiki](https://bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=site&only=scripts&skin=vector&*)). So, you need to look at web sniffer to identify it:
[image]

What to do? If you want to retrieve the whole page content, you better plugin any of libraries working out (evaluating) in page javascript. Read more [here](http://scraping.pro/javascript-protected-content-scrape/).

### Update

> I am not interested in retrieving the whole page and statistics or JS libraries retrieved from MediaWiki. I only need the whole content of the page (through scraping, not MediaWiki API).

The issue is that those js calls to other resources (incl. mediawiki) make possible to render the WHOLE page to client. But since the library does not support JS execution, js is not executed => page parts are not loaded from other resources => target page is not whole.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful. However, I am not interested in retrieving the whole page and statistics or JS libraries retrieved from MediaWiki. I only need the whole content of the page (through scraping, not MediaWiki API). More interestingly, this problem does not happen when you request small pages. It only happens when the page is larger than a specific size.

Comment: @user2521204 just curious, what is that specific size?

Comment: @user2521204, are there any limits set in `request` library?

Comment: @Karl, sorry for my late response. Actually, I have received different large sizes, such as 142105, 16110, 131760, ...

Comment: As you can see these are totally different from each other, and i don't think we can conclude there is s limit on the size. However, in all of these cases, while urllib2 has retrieved the complete content, requests.get has retrieved a partial one. From another point of view, I did the same thing on other pages with a comparable length (108540, 30433, 40085, ...) and it requests.get retrieves them completely. Comparing these numbers suggests that we should be suspicious about a similar issue that @Igor Savinkin has explained, but I don't understand why urllib2 retrieves them completely.